# 8086 assembly relative addressing issue

Tags: assembly, 8086, real-mode, addressing

This tiny program puts a few A's into the text mode buffer of an ms-dos pc. But only works if the number of repetitions (CX) is loaded with a direct value. If I try to read that from memory, i.e. using 'mov cx, [cols]' then random garbage happens.

It's maybe related to the fact, that DS has been set to the beginning of the text mode buffer.
But it's set only afterwards, so I have no idea.

**UPDATE**: I cannot reproduce the bug. The code works just as expected. Thanks for the effort. Marked the answer because of the added value.

Using MS-DOS 6.22, NASM version 0.98.39

```
        org 100h

        mov cx, 5       ;[cols] should read the reserved word from the end part, but causes freezing instead
        mov bx, 0       ;offset

        mov ax, 0B800h  ;VGA text buffer
        mov ds, ax
do:
        mov word [bx], 0741h   ;gray A character
        add bx, 2
        loop do
exit:
        mov ah, 4Ch
        mov al, 2    ;exit code
        int 21h

cols:   dw 5         ;number of repetitions
```

Comment: DS should be set to same segment so it should work. Have you single-stepped the program in debug.exe to find out if CX ends up being 5 or not when loaded from memory, and if the address from where it is loaded is correct?

Comment: It's been years since I did any 8086 assembly so I may be wrong here - there shouldn't be a colon after 'cols' at the end. You're defining it as a label and not as a variable.

Comment: @No'am Newman: Colon or no colon does not matter here in NASM assembly language.

Comment: Your program works for me with `[cols]` instead of `5`. I used NASM 2.14, with `-fbin`.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this program. You have not described what ‘random garbage’ happens to look like. Were this Stack Overflow, this would have qualified for closure as either ‘needs debugging details’ or ‘not reproducible’.

Comment: Please provide the command line(s) to produce the executable.

Comment: Updated the question, becuase I myself cannot reproduce the problem. It's my fault and thanks for the help.

Comment: the command line I use is simple: nasm fill.asm -o fill.com

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s asking for help with a problem which can’t be reproduced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in [Justme’s answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/21671/79), there’s nothing inherently wrong with your code, and building a `.COM` file with

```
nasm -fbin -oloop.com loop.asm
```

produces a 29-byte file which works fine.

However there are a number of improvements you could make to your code:

```
        org 100h

        mov ax, 0B800h  ;VGA text buffer
        mov es, ax
        xor di, di      ;offset
        mov ax, 0741h   ;gray A character
        mov cx, [cols]
        rep stosw
        mov ax, 4C02h
        int 21h

        align 2
cols:   dw 5         ;number of repetitions
```

This uses [`stosw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/stos:stosb:stosw:stosd:stosq) to store the word value given by `AX` in the memory location pointed to by `ES:DI`, increasing `DI` as appropriate after each store (depending on the setting of the `DF` flag; the default is to increment). The `rep` prefix causes the instruction to repeat until `CX` is 0, decrementing `CX` after each invocation. This leaves `DS` alone, which simplifies data access — I relied on that to load `CX` just before the `rep`, making it easier to see the loop count.

I’ve also combined the two stores in `AH` and `AL` before invoking interrupt 0x21.

(This also saves five bytes, but the idea here isn’t to code-golf!)

Comment: I would add `align 2` before the `cols` label and variable. If you don't codegolf you can afford the alignment to make your code more efficient.

Comment: align is a nasm keyword? or x86 instruction?

Comment: It’s an assembler directive, like `org` and `dw`; widely supported, but not an x86 instruction.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing inherently wrong in the source code.

Most likely explanation is that the NASM compiler was not told to output the binary in COM format and the memory offset of the variable which contains the value 5 is wrong.

Which would have been clearly visible if the COM file had been loaded into debug for disassembly or tracing the code.